# Difficulties extracting XML from Word document with Python

Tags: python, xml, docx

I'm trying to extract the XML from a Word document with Python using the code found on [this](http://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/) webpage.

I began by creating a test document named `test.docx`. I then ran the following code:

```
import zipfile
from lxml import etree

def getXml(docxFilename):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(docxFilename))
    xmlContent = zip.read("word/document.xml")
    return xmlContent

def getXmlTree(xmlContent):
    return etree.fromstring(xmlContent)

testXml = getXml("test.docx")
print(getXmlTree(testXml))
```

Running this code produced the error message "File is not a zip file". What did I do wrong?

Comment: which version of Python?  Also have you googled "File is not a zip file" and looked at those questions/answers?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4. Yes I tried googling and while there are plenty of discussions of this error I didn't find anything particular to unzipping Word documents.

Comment: I tested your script on cygwin python 2.7.8 and it worked fine. Are you able to use the "unzip" utility on the docx file? perhaps it is corrupted.

Comment: Try opening the file in "rb" mode

Comment: @patrickmdnet As stupid as this sounds I thought that zipfile.ZipFile did the unzipping. How do I unzip a document? @tdelaney When I tried adding a "rb" mode, I got the error `ZipFile() requires mode "r", "w", or "a"`. When I used mode "r", I got the same error as before. However, when I used mode "w" or mode "a", I got a new error: `"There is no item named 'word/document.xml' in the archive"`

Comment: @tdelaney Nevermind it works now. I realized I added the "rb" in the wrong function (ZipFile() instead of open()). Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the path of docx file as a argument, not particularly docx file.
compress the file and make the path in zip format

ex:
"D:/Users/John/docs/data.zip"